# install airflow with python3 and postgres + google cloud

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am trying to install apache airflow with postgres, particularly `PostgresToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` but when I run through this pipeline, it is still not installed.  What needs to happen to install all of the postgres contrib classes?

```
pip install airflow
pip install google-cloud-dataflow==2.2.0
pip install "apache-airflow[gcp_api, postgres]"
```

Comment: What does "it is still not installed" mean? What output do you have?

Comment: If you check inside my python directory in the virtual environment, `postgres_to_gcs_operator.py` is not in the `contrib.operator` directory

Comment: Is the reason you're self-rolling it because you need Python 3? You could use [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) and save some time. :)

Comment: I wanted to use cloud composer, but the powers that be want otherwise.  Unfortunately I can't explain here :-O